# ERROR: Web3 not defined

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask, require, browsers

I'm trying to build a browser UI to interact with my Solidity smart contract that is deployed on my local Ganache blockchain. But I can't seem to get my index.html file to connect to Metamask. I keep getting this error when opening my index.html in Chrome:

```
main.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: Web3 is not defined
    at main.js:5
(anonymous) @ main.js:5
```

Github repo: https://github.com/Lennardmulder/Mannencoin

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Error says it all, you are missing the web3 library in your local project. Simply follow the steps [**here**](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js#readme) for downloading the library and how to attach it to your project. There are examples for nodejs, browser of typescript enviroments.